# Цикл для получения строки из тега, BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Я пытаюсь собрать некоторую информацию с сайта http://scpfoundation.net/scp-021 с помощью `Python` и библиотеки `BeautifulSoup`.

Мне нужно получить значение строки внутри тега `<p>` я делаю это следующим образом:

```
for text in soup.find_all('p',):
   text_scp.append(text.string)
```

Но получаю информацию не из всех тегов `<p>`. Например текст из такого: `<p><strong>Описание:</strong>"строка, которую мне нужно получить"</p>` я не получаю (может ли на это влиять тег `<strong>`). Подскажите как можно было бы решить эту проблему.

Comment: `может ли на это влиять тег <strong>` не может. Добавьте ссылку на сайт и ожидаемый результат

Comment: gil9red, http://scpfoundation.net/scp-021 нужно получить всю текстовую информацию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример кода для возврата тегов `p` из тега с `id="page-content"`. Для получения текста тега и из его вложенных тегов используется функция `get_text` (это отличается от поведения поля `string`).

Пример:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

rs = requests.get('http://scpfoundation.net/scp-021')
root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')

for p in root.select('#page-content p'):
    print(p.get_text(strip=True))
```

Результат:

```
Объект №:SCP-021
Класс объекта:Безопасный
Особые условия содержания:SCP-021 является облигатным паразитом человеческого тела. Соответственно, сдерживание его не сложнее сдерживания взрослого человека; обычной камеры достаточно. SCP-021 в настоящее время расположен в камере заключения 217-A на субъекте D-139. Носителями SCP-021 могут быть только сотрудники класса D. На время носительства SCP-021 субъект освобождается от ежемесячного устранения сотрудников класса D.
Описание:SCP-021 принимает форму большой, очень детализированной татуировки змеевидного дракона в восточном стиле, занимая около 0,8 квадратных метров кожи. Эта татуировка способна целиком двигаться в пределах кожи хозяина и в целом ведет себя как обычное животное, но в двух измерениях. Движение татуировки причиняет носителю постоянную боль, аналогичную по своему характеру одновременному нанесению и удалению татуировок, но в большем масштабе. Организм стремится проводить большую часть своего времени на туловище или поблизости. SCP-021 не проявляет признаков разумности, помимо базовых потребностей в еде и передвижении, хотя сами попытки измерить разумность двумерного существа пока что невозможны.
SCP-021 питается только пигментами кожи носителя. В их число входит и меланин, и в этом случае у субъекта проявляются симптомы витилиго. Примечательно, что организм предпочитает природным пигментам другие татуировки и будет искать и пожирать их, прежде чем переключится на натуральные пигменты. Следует отметить, что носителю причиняет боль только передвижение объекта. Татуировочные чернила обычно просто исчезают, будучи "съеденными". Организм поддерживает постоянный размер, выделений не наблюдается. За час организм может очистить около 0.6 квадратных метров кожи. SCP-021 можно "покормить", если (быстро) вытатуировать на носителе фрукты или мелких животных.
SCP-021 может быть перемещён от одного носителя другому разными способами физического контакта, с разной вероятностью успеха. В случае успешной передачи организм просто «переплывает» с одного человека на другого. Половой акт, похоже, наиболее надежный способ передачи, он успешен в 93% случаев. Однако из-за сильной боли, сопровождающей процесс, этот способ далеко не идеален. Контакт между двумя открытыми ранами обычно предпочтительнее. Передача мертвым субъектам сложнее, но имеет основание: объект не страдает из-за смерти субъекта и продолжает есть пигментные пятна. Случаи передачи между разными биологическими видами неизвестны; раннее проведенные опыты подразумевают, что это будет либо невозможным, либо вероятность успеха будет крайне мала.
SCP-021 дает носителю некоторую пользу. Доказано, что татуировка ускоряет расход и повторное поглощение адреналина и снижает накопление молочной кислоты, что дает увеличение силы, уверенности, болевого порога в стрессовых ситуациях и уменьшение последствий слабости и усталости. Кроме того, татуировка, похоже, положительно влияет на иммунную систему носителя. Агрессия носителей, как правило, выше среднего, хотя предстоит выяснить, является ли это прямым влиянием татуировки или просто реакцией на постоянную боль.
Симбиотические отношения обычно продолжаются до тех пор, пока носитель может терпеть боль в повседневной жизни. Из-за неё некоторые субъекты оканчивали жизнь самоубийством. В редких случаях носители погибали от смертельного заражения кожи.
Природа и происхождение SCP-021 неизвестны. Запись передачи организма от одного к другому вряд ли осуществима в условиях секретности, а SCP-021 вполне может быть несколько сотен лет, если не больше. Тем не менее, SCP-021 является одним из самых старых объектов в Фонде, он хранится уже [ДАННЫЕ УДАЛЕНЫ] лет и является источником большого количества информации. Текущие исследования направлены преимущественно на наблюдение свойств жизни в двух измерениях.
```